# Ajax call to localhost from app running on IPhone device using Expo

Tags: android, ios, ajax, react-native, expo

I am using the logic below for choosing an ip address for making ajax call to Api which is running on localhost and its working fine when I use emulator on my laptop, but when I use expo on an IPhone device to load my app the ajax call fails and can not make the connection with the Api, I also tried my machine local ip in network and 127.0.0.1 but none of them works.

`const SERVER_URL = __DEV__ ?
Platform.select({
  ios: "http://localhost:5000",
  android: "http://10.0.2.2:5000"
}) : "https://exmple.com"`

Comment: When running on an iPhone `localhost` will be *the iphone* - You need to use the IP address of your server/workstation and ensure that there are no firewalls etc preventing access.

Comment: I added a exception role for that port and used my machine ip but still cant access.